# How to fill a 2D area with N 2D quads of different shapes but same area?

Tags: geometry-nodes, add-on, geometry

I have a 1000 m² N-gon of a curved shape. I want to cut it in 100 10 m² pieces and have a look at different variants of filling. Like manually changing the shape of one piece and have other pieces reshaping automatically. Or at least anything like this to give me the right research direction.

**Is there an addon for this?**
**Or a geometry nodes example?**

I have looked through a bunch of them with no avail.